# Move Windows 7 Gadget with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, windows-desktop-gadgets

I already resize a gadget when a certain button is pressed using this code:

```
with (document.body.style)
{
    width = "987px";
    height = "773px";
}
```

The complaint I get from users is that it goes off their screen because the gadget maintains it's top-left position and "grows" from that point. Is there any way to move the gadget relative to its current position? I've tried window.moveTo without success.

Comment: `with` is the bane of all evil. It's _evil_.